# How to run a keycloak as second container after first container postgres Database start up at multi-container pod environment of kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, keycloak

In a multi-container pod:

step-1: Deploy first container Postgres Database and create a schema

step-2: Wait until the Postgres pod came up

step-3: then start deploying second container keycloak

I have written below deployment file to run :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: idms
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: idms
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: idms
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: idms
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: postgres
         image: registry.prod.srv.da.nsn-rdnet.net/edge/postgres:12.3-alpine
         imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
         ports:
           - containerPort: 5432
         lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command: ["/bin/bash","-c","sleep 5 && PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql $POSTGRES_DB -U $POSTGRES_USER -c \'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS keycloak;\'"]  
         envFrom:
           - configMapRef:
               name: postgres-config
       - name: keycloak
         image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.1
         env:
          - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
            value: "admin"
          - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
            value: "admin"
          - name: REALM
            value: "ntc"
          - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
            value: "true"
          - name: DB_ADDR
            value: "localhost"
          - name: DB_PORT
            value: "5432"
          - name: DB_DATABASE
            value: "postgresdb"
          - name: DB_USER
            value: "xxxxxxxxx"
          - name: DB_PASSWORD
            value: "xxxxxxxxx"
          - name: DB_SCHEMA
            value: "keycloak"    
          - name: KEYCLOAK_IMPORT
            value: "/opt/jboss/keycloak/startup/elements/realm.json"
         volumeMounts:
           - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
             name: postgredb 
           - mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/startup/elements
             name: elements 
         ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8080
          - name: https
            containerPort: 8443
         readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /auth/realms/master
              port: 8080
      volumes:
        - name: elements
          configMap:
            name: keycloak-elements
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

but keycloak is starting with H2 embedded database instead of Postgres. if I am using init-container to `nslookup` on Postgres on deployment file like below :

```
initContainers:
      - name: init-postgres
        image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup postgres; do echo waiting for postgres; sleep 2; done;']
```

pod is getting stuck at "podinitialization"

Comment: It seems like you'd want to run those two things in separate pods.  In the Keycloak deployment, you'd connect to the name of the Service in front of the separate PostgreSQL deployment.  (If you need to upgrade or reconfigure Keycloak, you wouldn't want to also have to restart the database at the same time.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Agree. Initially, we ran those two deployments at separate pod only. currently, we reached the 100 pod limit per node at the Kubernetes cluster. so we are reducing pod as much as possible until we get more infrastructure to deploy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forget to add the

```
- name: DB_VENDOR
  value: POSTGRES
```

in the deployment YAML file due to that keycloak by default using the H2 database mode.

YAML ref file : https://github.com/harsh4870/Keycloack-postgres-kubernetes-deployment/blob/main/keycload-deployment.yaml

Comment: glad to hear that. @SiddhantaRath